# Removing Blue Border around treeviewitem in Expression Blend

Tags: silverlight, border

I'm building a silverlight app in Blend that will contain a treeview and treeviewitems.  The contents of my treeviewitems all have a blue border (when clicked and when you hover the mouse over), as you can see in the image I linked to.  I cannot figure out what causes that border, or how to remove it; anyone know where to get at it?  I've tried looking in the various treeview related templates, but I've had no luck so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are seeing here is the FocusVisual:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.focusvisualstyle.aspx

If you set this to {x:Null} (via FocusVisualStyle), it should go away...if not, you're likely dealing with a "selected" VisualState, in which case your best option is to override the template to remove that particular state.